# Highlight Row in Red up to certain column if cell contains certain value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small macro that highlights an entire row in red if the cell value in J column contains the value 427.See below...

```
Dim lr As Long
lr = Worksheets("owssvr").Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

         Dim cell As Range  
            For Each cell In Range("J2:J" & lr)
               If cell.Value = 427 Then
               cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 255     
    End If
```

What I would like to do is to amend the macro so that it only highlights in red the section of the row that contains data, rather than the entire row (in this tables case, up to column AF). Thank you.

Comment: [Use conditional formatting to highlight information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f). There is no need for VBA here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to highlight row between columns `A` & `F` then try-

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim lr As Long
lr = Worksheets("owssvr").Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Range("J2:J" & lr)
        If cel.Value = 427 Then
           Range("A" & lr & ":F" & lr).Interior.Color = 255
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The OPs code will fail unless `owssvr` is the `ActiveSheet`. I highly recommend to specify the worksheet for **all** `Range` and ̀ Cells` objects!